# Is nikah haram with son wife If son is dead?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, islamic-philosophy

Is Nikah be allowed by father with his son's wife when his son has expired ? Is the Nikah halal or haram ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? This question would be vastly improved if you added details and showed research effort. I would strongly suggest you check out the advice in our help centre on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" for advice on the sorts of questions encouraged by the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 2):

It's haram "forever" before or after son's death. This is according to Quran, Surat An-Nisa' [4:23]:

> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are your mothers, your daughters, your sisters, your father's sisters, your mother's sisters, your brother's daughters, your sister's daughters, your [milk] mothers who nursed you, your sisters through nursing, your wives' mothers, and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in unto them, there is no sin upon you. And [also prohibited are] the wives of your sons who are from your [own] loins, and that you take [in marriage] two sisters simultaneously, except for what has already occurred. Indeed, Allah is ever Forgiving and Merciful.
>
> http://quran.com/4/23

In this Ayah, The word that is used to describe "the wives of your sons" is: "حلائل" "hala-ilu" which means: the women who are (and who have been)  "halal" for your sons i.e. the women who are (and who have been) wives of your sons.

Comment: When the son dies, it's not his wife anymore.  Same with divorce.

Comment: The answer is edited